# How to color node wires in node editor?

Tags: node-editor

Is there any way to color wires in node editor? If not, are there any add-ons for coloring wires based on the body color of the output node? It seems like it should be pretty simple to do and I've downloaded textures with colored wires but I have no idea how it was done.

Comment: What do you mean by "color node wires"? Can you show a screenshot? Do you mean interface of nodes in the Node Editor?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to achieve an effect similar to the one you get with the Blender internal renderer, you can use the `Wireframe` node to separate edges from the rest:

[image: Wireframe]

The white (1) regions are at the specified distance from the edges, and the black (0) regions are not. You can pass these values to the mix shader to use separate shaders for these two regions:

[image: mix]

Comment: should have been more specific, sorry i meant, the actual wires in the node editor connecting the nodes cuz im getting huge messy webs of wires it would help if i could color the wires

Comment: @zander oh, I see what you mean now. I don't think you can color them individually. You can only change the color of all wires if you change the theme. If you want your nodes to be more organized, you can use the [node framing](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/node_editor/nodes/frame.html) feature.

Comment: unfortunately its not something i can frame, i have to drag a bunch of separated xyz values into a bunch of nodes and i wanted to see if i could color the x/y/z wires different colors so i didnt mix them up

Comment: @zander, I don't know then, but maybe someone else does. If you clarify your question, as mr zak suggested, you are more likely to get the answer you want.